# Call descendant's method from ancestor's methods and constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, parameters, constructor

Next code presents class-parameter-wrapper, it allows to access underlying class via getters and setters. Simplified version:

```
template<typename T>
class Parameter
{
public:
    typedef T value_type;
    typedef Parameter<T> Type;
protected:
    T value_;
public:
    Parameter() { this->value_ = this->default_value(); }
    Parameter(T&& val) { this->set(std::forward<T>(val)); }
    Parameter(const T& val) { this->set(std::forward<T>(val)); }
    virtual ~Parameter() {};

    // Get
    T& get() { return this->value_/*this->getter()*/; }
    operator T&() { return this->get(); }

    // Set
    Type& set(T&& val)
    {
        std::cout << "T&& setter called with " << val << std::endl;
        value_ = this->setter(std::forward<T>(val));
        return *this;
    }
    Type& set(const T& val)
    {
        std::cout << "constT& setter called with " << val << std::endl;
        value_ = this->setter(std::forward<const T>(val));
        return *this;
    }
    Type& operator=(T const& val) { return this->set(val); }
    Type& operator=(T&& val) { return this->set(val); }

    virtual T setter(T const& val) { return val; }

    virtual const T& default_value()
    {
        static const T default_value_{};
        return default_value_;
    };
};
```

Using:

```
int main()
{
    struct IncrementorPar : Parameter<int>
    {
        using Parameter::Parameter;  //todo HIDE
        using Parameter::operator=;  //todo HIDE
        virtual int setter(int const& val) { return val + 1; }
        virtual const int& default_value(){ return -1; };
    } in1(1), in2 = 2, int0;
    //assert(int0==int0.default_value());  //FAIL
    //assert(int0==-1);  //FAIL
    //assert(in1 == 2);  //FAIL
    //assert(in2 == 3);  //FAIL
    auto *pi1 = new IncrementorPar(2);
    //assert(*pi1==3);  //FAIL
    pi1->set(2);
    assert(*pi1==3);
    *pi1 = 33;}
}
```

How could it be possible to **call descendant's methods `setter()` and `default_value()` from ancestor's constructor?**
How can I hide `using`'s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really an elegant solution but...

You could postpone the initialization of `value_` using a `init()` function.

Something like

```
template<typename T>
class Parameter
{
private:
    bool  toInit { true };
    bool  initWithVal;
    T     valInit;

    void init ()
     {
       if ( initWithVal )
          this->set(valInit);
       else
          value_ = this->default_value();

       toInit = false;
     }

public:
    typedef T value_type;
    typedef Parameter<T> Type;
protected:
    T value_;
public:
    Parameter() : initWithVal{false} { }
    Parameter(T&& val) : initWithVal{true}, valInit{std::move(val)} { }
    Parameter(const T& val) { this->set(std::forward<T>(val)); }
    virtual ~Parameter() {};

    // Get
    T& get() { if ( toInit ) init(); return this->value_/*this->getter()*/; }
    operator T&() { return this->get(); }

    // Set
    Type& set(T&& val)
    {
      toInit = false;
      std::cout << "T&& setter called with " << val << std::endl;
      value_ = this->setter(std::forward<T>(val));
      return *this;
    }
    Type& set(const T& val)
    {
      toInit = false;
      std::cout << "constT& setter called with " << val << std::endl;
      value_ = this->setter(std::forward<const T>(val));
      return *this;
    }
    Type& operator=(T const& val) { return this->set(val); }
    Type& operator=(T&& val) { return this->set(val); }

    virtual T setter(T const& val) { return val; }

    virtual const T& default_value()
    {
      std::cout << "base default value\n";
        static const T default_value_{};
        return default_value_;
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

## Explanation

It's not possible to call descendant's methods from ancestor's, without overriding the constructor of each derived class, as during construction, the `vtable` has information on only the so-far-constructed classes, in the order of constructor calls (which as we recall, is base -> most derived).

Excerpt аrom the [forum](http://computer-programming-forum.com/81-vc/dce8444437d51df0.htm):

> I have a class which calls from its constructor a virtual method `Init()`.
>   In the descendants I override this virtual method `Init()`. And the idea is
>   that whenever I create a descendant, I want the descendant's `Init()` to be
>   called, not the ancestors! And I dont want to override the constructor for
>   that, because I'd have to override the constructors of every descendants
>   then. How is it possible?

answer

> It's not possible without overriding the constructor of each derived class,
>   as during construction, the `vtable` has information on only the
>   so-far-constructed classes, in the order of constructor calls (which as we
>   recall, is base -> most derived). So when `ClassA`'s constructor gets called,
>   despite it being an instance of `ClassB`, the virtual function mechanism will
>   have access to `ClassB`'s overrides for `ClassA`'s functions only *after*
>   `ClassA`'s constructor has finished executing, so anytime you call a virtual
>   function from `ClassA::ClassA()`, `ClassA::Init()` will be called.
>    -- Dan

### Solution

use init guides-variables as @max66 suggested, or something similar.